# How to Export multiple classes in a single library in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have two JS classes in different files like this:

```
// Class1.js
export default class Class1 { /* ... */ }

// Class2.js
import Class1 from './Class1'
export default class Class2 { /* ... */ }
```

And an `index.js` file that exports both

```
// index.js
import Class1 from './Class1'
import Class2 from './Class2'

export default {Class1, Class2}
```

And I'm using webpack to bundle them

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true
  },
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'my-lib.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'MyLib'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
}

// package.json
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "dist/my-lib.js",
  "module": "src/index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

However, when I try to use them in a separate project:

```
// MyComponent.js
import {Class2} from 'my-lib'
```

I get this warning:

> WARN  in ./MyComponent.js
>
> "export 'Class2' was not found in 'my-lib'

Why? It's clearly being exported in the `index.js` file. How can I fix this? Is there even a right way to do this or do I have to create a different library for every class I need?

Comment: i think you should remove default from export, i.e `export {Class1, Class2}`

Comment: Nope, I get the same warning

Comment: See this example [multi-part-library](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library)